# What's the version of PostgreSQL that has pgAdmin 4 v2.1 included?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I need to know which of these packages has the pgAdmin 4 v2.1 included with PostgreSQL:

https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/

I found pgAdmin alone in this link:

https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/windows/

But I want the binary of PostgreSQL that has pgAdmin 4 v2.1 included, not pgAdmin by itself, and I didn't find any info about what release of PostgreSQL has the pgAdmin 4 in version 2.1.

Comment: Postgres is not bundled with pgAdmin. It's the other way round: the Windows installer for Postgres includes pgAdmin. You should simply install pgAdmin independently from Postgres https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pgAdmin is included in PostgreSQL when you download the latter.

Comment: @LP0956 that's what a_horse_with_no_name said. Also, that it doesn't matter which *tool* version is included with one PosgreSQL version or another, `pgAdmin` is a separate program. The only thing you should care about is which `pgAdmin` version supports the PostgreSQL version you want.

Comment: @LP0956 for example, Amazon's Redshift used to behave like a very old version of PostgreSQL that required downloading an old pgAdmin version. Which version do you want to connect to?